# Images available?

Tags: search, patent-figures

In reference to the patent: [US9045201](https://www.google.com/patents/US9045201)

I would like to know if all this images are available anywhere to better understand the meaning of this document.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why they are not available at google, but if you follow for example the [espacenet link](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/originalDocument?CC=US&NR=9045201B1&KC=B1&FT=D&ND=&date=20150602&DB=&locale=#) (at the google page at the right where it says external links) or the [USPTO link](http://pdfpiw.uspto.gov/.piw?Docid=09045201&homeurl=http%3A%2F%2Fpatft.uspto.gov%2Fnetacgi%2Fnph-Parser%3FSect2%3DPTO1%2526Sect2%3DHITOFF%2526p%3D1%2526u%3D%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html%2526r%3D1%2526f%3DG%2526l%3D50%2526d%3DPALL%2526S1%3D9045201.PN.%2526OS%3DPN%2F9045201%2526RS%3DPN%2F9045201&PageNum=&Rtype=&SectionNum=&idkey=NONE&Input=View%20first%20page) you will find the images.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that "www.google.com/patents" often has issues with displaying images and really shouldn't be used. If you really want to use Google then use the site "patents.google.com". Here is the same patent at [patents.google.com](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9045201B1/en). You'll notice that the images are displayed. Another option is [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/). It is also completely free, but if you register, you get various useful advantages including the ability to save searches. I find it better and more reliable than Google for searching patents. Here is the same patent found on [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/patent/US_9045201_B1).

Of course you can also use the official sites provided by DonQuiKong. I find "patents.google.com" and "www.lens.org/lens" easier and faster.